# Angular2 with CLI + Boot Strap4 Failed to execute 'setRequestHeader' on 'XMLHttpRequest': 'Authorization: Bearer '

Tags: angular, jwt, angular-cli

Environments – Angular2 with CLI + Boot Strap4 is Front End ( localhost:4200)
Spring boot + Security +JWT + REST Ful Controllers for Back End (localhost:8080)

Chrome is giving the Failed to execute 'setRequestHeader' on 'XMLHttpRequest': 'Authorization: Bearer ' is not a valid HTTP header field name the same piece of code is working fine with IE.

I have been breaking my head from last two weeks and did lot of googling and unable to resolve the issue. As I am running out of time I am posting this question here hoping some Angular2 Gods will provide suggestions to resolve this issue.

Environments – Angular2 with CLI + Boot Strap4 is Front End ( localhost:4200)
Spring boot + Security +JWT + REST Ful Controllers for Back End (localhost:8080)

Here is the scenario:

Login Screen

Onsubmit - Passing the Credentials to the Spring Boot Security to Authenticate.

onSubmit() {

```
 this.loginService.authenticateUser(this.loginUserDtls)
 .subscribe( 
  data => {
    let token=  JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))._body;
    console.log("TOKEN  VALUE "+token) ;
    this.loginService.sendToken(token).subscribe( 
    data => {
        let dataRet=  JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))._body;
        console.log("data received  "+dataRet);
     }
    )

 });
```

On Successful authentication Spring Security generating the JWT Token   and sending the token back to fort end keeping it in the response header as below

response.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + JWT);

Issue 1- 
 Some reason Angular 2 (localhost:4200) response header is missing the Authorization header details   which is placed in the Spring Boot Security Services (localhost:8080)

For Issue 1- I had a workaround by sending the JWT token in the response body.

After extracting the token the from response body, I am invoking a different restful service by passing token in the Angular 2 request Header as below :

sendToken(token)  {

```
var headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer '+ token);
headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');

return this.http.get('http://localhost:8082/users', {headers:headers});
```

}

The above worked is working fine in IE but when testing the same thing in Chrome getting  the 
 Failed to execute 'setRequestHeader' on 'XMLHttpRequest': 'Authorization: Bearer ' is not a valid HTTP header field name. Also please verify the screenshot for more detailed console log.

I had tried the above code with RequestOptions withCredentials = true also but no luck with Chrome.

Please kindly post your suggestions to resolve the issue.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQdL3.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to resolve this issue. This issue is due to CORS. Chrome is making a preflight and server is not setting headers due to this during actual call chrome is not able to recognize Authorization header.